# Dropdown Menu in CSS/Styles

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I would like the to have a dropdown menu fall from the "treatments tab with a mouse hover. It would be ideal if "treatments.html" could just be a button and not a link.

1.) The menu bar remains sticky at the top of the web page
2.) Treatments tab has dropdown options
3.) Treatments becomes button and not a link

HTML

```
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="UL.css">

<title>Home</title>

<div class="parallax"></div>

</head>

<div class="stripes">
<body>

<div class="navbar">
    <a href="contact-us.html" target="_top">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="products-gifts.html" target="_top">Products & Gifts</a>
    <a href="treatments.html" target="_top">Treatments</a>
    <a href="home.html" target="_top">Home</a>
</div>

<div class="main">

<h1>Welcome to Undercover Laser</h1>

</div>

</body>
</div>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.parallax {
       background-image: url("images/IMG_5026.jpg");
       min-height: 680px;
       background-attachment: fixed;
       background-position: center;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-size: cover;
       }

body {
  margin:0;
  }

.stripes {
      background-image: url("images/stripes.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }

.navbar {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: rgba(49,49,49,0.85);
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
float: right;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
float: left;
display: block;
color: #f2f2f2;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 15px;
float: right;
}

.navbar a:hover {
      background-color: #ff008f;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      }

.main {
padding: 16px;
margin-top: 30px;
height: auto;
}

h1 {
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 75px;
color: #FF008F;
text-align: center;
}

h2 {
font-family: Caslon, serif;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #000000;
margin-left:50px;
}

p {
font-family: Caslon, serif;
color: #000000;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-right: 50px;
font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Is it not working?

Comment: @NisargShah Only problem is the treatments tab. I have other html documents I would like to attach in a dropdown menu only to that treatments tab

Answer (score 1):

What you want is when mouse hover a tab that has child related pages, it shows below it so user can click subpages (Childs).
You really don't have to make one tab a button while other are not!.

To achieve this you have to to use positioning as follows:
- Parent container is the anchor (link) with `position: relative;`

- Child `<div>` with

`position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;`

This will make the `<div>` just below the tab.